# How to create a spatial polygon from 2 known spatial data points in r?

Tags: r, polygon

I have 2 spatial data points which have UTM coordinates.
I want to create spatial polygons of 100x20m using these 2 points as boundary references (see picture).

[image]

Background: This for the purpose of assigning carbon values to these polygons.
I've done an inventory some inventory work within these boundaries.
How do I create these polygons in R?

Comment: use the point coordinates to create a bbox `st_bbox()` on a named vector with xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax elements -- then `st_as_sfc()` that to get a POLYGON.

Comment: Do the two points always have the same Y (latitude) coordinate?

Comment: How is each pair of points represented in your data? Are you using `sp` or `sf` spatial data classes or is this in a data frame with four numbers for the coordinates?

Comment: @Spacedman Not necessarily. Sometimes the plot is oriented N-S sometimes E-W (as is the case for the illustration)

Comment: But you want your output rectangle to be aligned with the line between the two points?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes. Exactly.

Comment: So the points in the pair have to be *exactly* 100m apart?